# JavaScript コード内に Java オブジェクトのフィールド値を Thymeleaf で展開したい

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

timepickerの時刻設定にオブジェクトのフィールド値を使って機能させたいのですが、
下記のようなソースの書き方だと時刻が表示されません。どう修正したらよろしいでしょうか。
defaultTime: "9:00"と書くと時間は表示される状態です。
※student.timeにはString型の"9:00"が入っています。

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.timepicker1').timepicker({
      showMeridian: false,
      minuteStep: 1,
      defaultTime: "${student.time}"
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: `"${...}"` で変数を展開する構文はJavascriptにはありませんが、なんの構文ですか？何故そのように書いたのでしょうか。

Comment: Thymeleafの構文に従って書きました。Javaのフレームワークはspring bootを使っています。

Comment: timepickerのinputタグにth:value属性を記載したら上手くいきました。ご指摘ありがとうございます‼

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
defaultTime: "${student.time}"
```

↓

```
defaultTime: /*[[${student.time}]]*/ "9:00"
```

参照: [スクリプトのインライン処理](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf_ja.html#%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%83%97%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E5%87%A6%E7%90%86-javascript-%E3%81%A8-dart)

Comment: timepickerのinputタグにth:value属性を記載したら上手くいきました。たくさんのアドバイスありがとうございました‼